# Inserting elements into the DOM in a jQuery Mobile based page

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I'm experimenting with a jQuery Mobile app that will eventually end up as a non-Web app on a mobile device and so all the content has to be local. For that reason (I think) I need to construct the app in a single page delineated by `data-role="page"` tags otherwise the ajax loading mechanism in jQuery Mobile doesn't seem to work.

The app will read data from a local storage DB and display it on the page in an unordered list, styled using jQuery Mobile to look like a native app.

In my `$(document).ready()` function I execute the DB lookup and for each results, I create an `<li>` tag around my DB results and then call `$(".list").append(li_str);` where `.list` is the class of my `<ul>` tag.

The page renders as if jQuery Mobile isn't present - I see the correct data in each `<li>` but it doesn't look correct.

Comparing this result with a version where I hard code the `<li>` tags in the page HTML - it looks like jQuery Mobile modifies the tags and inserts a lot of new classes etc.

Maybe I need to build the page from the DB earlier in the page load cycle? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is [**this issue**](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/style-timing-issue-with-dynamic-content-in-jquery-mobile). So, change your code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0a2/jquery.mobile-1.0a2.min.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0a2/jquery.mobile-1.0a2.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    function build_dynamic_content()
    {
        var num_entries = 5;

        for (var i = 0; i < num_entries; ++i)
        {
            var li_str = "<li id=\"" + i + "\"><a href=\"#\">" + "Entry number " + ( i + 1 ) + "</a>";
            li_str += "<img src=\"" + "icon.png" + "\" />";
            li_str += "</li>";

            $(".mainlist").append(li_str);
        }
    }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div data-role="page" id="list" data-fullscreen="false">
        <div data-role="content">
            <ul class="mainlist" data-role="listview">
                <li id="0"><a href="#">Test entry</a><img src="icon.png"/></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
<script>build_dynamic_content();</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Alternately, you can delay creating the list view until all of the elements have been created (as described in the linked thread):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0a2/jquery.mobile-1.0a2.min.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0a2/jquery.mobile-1.0a2.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    function build_dynamic_content()
    {
        var num_entries = 5;

        for (var i = 0; i < num_entries; ++i)
        {
            var li_str = "<li id=\"" + i + "\"><a href=\"#\">" + "Entry number " + ( i + 1 ) + "</a>";
            li_str += "<img src=\"" + "icon.png" + "\" />";
            li_str += "</li>";

            $(".mainlist").append(li_str);
        }
    }

    $(function ()
    {
        build_dynamic_content();
        $('ul.mainlist').listview();
    });
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div data-role="page" id="list" data-fullscreen="false">
        <div data-role="content">
            <ul class="mainlist">
                <li id="0"><a href="#">Test entry</a><img src="icon.png"/></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Sorry for code dumps; I couldn't get this working in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net).

Comment: That didn't appear to make any different Matt. I made a little test app with no DB that exhibits the problem. The first entry in the list is hard coded and looks correct. The rest are generated dynamically and do not:

http://pastebin.com/1LTDZ4nE

Can you see what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: @speed: you're welcome. The pastebin definitely helped, though a http://jsfiddle.net or http://jsbin.com is even better (next time :)

Answer (score 9):

Neither calling `$("changed-parent-element").listview()` nor `$("changed-parent-element").trigger("create")` really worked for me. 
In order to change the DOM content multiple times and redo the jQuery mobile styling I needed this:

```
$("changed-parent-element").listview("refresh");
```

Version: jQuery mobile 1.0 RC2

Answer (score 4):

Matt's answer is not a general answer to the question. I've already covered that a lot of times in other questions.

The above works with a listview, but not with any content in general.

To add elements to DOM in jQuery Mobile you need to know the .page() function.

I did a tutorial on that
http://jquerymobiledictionary.pl/faq.html

Comment: This site is not reachable, which is unfortunate because it contains the only correct answer to the OP's problem...

Found on http://jquerymobiledictionary.pl/faq.html:

=> after updating the DOM, call trigger('create') on the inserted element, like so:

$('#myelement').html('updated content').trigger('create');

Comment: Yes, I relocated the site to a domain and I updated most of the posts, but there are so many almost-duplicates, I didn't find all of them. Thanks for reporting.