# Jquery mobile theme on button in websql success call

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-mobile, web-sql

I am new to jQuery mobile and HTML5. I have created a page which has simple CRUD operation on WebSQL SQLite storage. It works well.

On the page I have buttons to insert and display information (using jQuery mobile)..on this button it displays jQuery mobile theme button and textbox correctly.
But on success callback Javascript, when I render the textbox and button, it displays like a normal HTML textbox and button.

Following is my code snippet.

**HTML:**

```html
<div id='riderResults'></div>
<a href="javascript:void(0);" data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-mini="true" data-theme="b" onClick="displayRider()" name="display" id="display">Add Report</a>
```

**Javascript:**

```js
function displayRider(){
  db.transaction(function(tx) {
    tx.executeSql("select * from riders", [], function(tx, result) {
      riderdataset = result.rows;
      for (var i = 0, item = null; i < riderdataset.length; i++) {
        item = riderdataset.item(i);
        var output='';
        output+='<div>'
             +'<input type="text" value="'+item['riderName']+'" name="name'+i+' id="name'+i+'"/>&nbsp;'
             +'<a href="javascript:void(0);" data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-mini="true" data-theme="b" onClick="updateRider('+i+')" name="update_rider" id="update_rider">Update Rider</a>'
             +'</div>';
      }
      document.getElementById('riderResults').innerHTML=output;
    });
  });
}
```

Please can any one give me proper direction where I was wrong..
Thanks.

Comment: I have got an answer here.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4952417/inserting-elements-into-the-dom-in-a-jquery-mobile-based-page. Need to trigger the element created like  this: $('#myelement').html('updated content').trigger('create');

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is you go to your browser and inspect the element of a button which was created by jquery-mobile then you copy the  tag of that element and put it in your var output. Because jquery-mobile add classes to your elements automatically depending on the data-role you told it.

The  tag should look like this:

```
<a data-role="button" data-transition="none" data-theme="a" href="#id" data-corners="true" data-shadow="true" data-iconshadow="true" data-iconsize="18" data-wrapperels="span" class="ui-btn ui-shadow ui-btn-corner-all ui-btn-icon-left ui-btn-up-a">
  <span class="ui-btn-inner ui-btn-corner-all">
    <span class="ui-btn-text">
      Button
    </span>
    <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-tab ui-icon-shadow ui-iconsize-18">
      &nbsp;
    </span>
  </span>
</a>
```